# In ReSharper 7, is it possible to extend syntax highlighting of strings?

Tags: c#, resharper

ReSharper has a fancy feature that highlights format variables in e.g. string.Format():

[image: string.Format]

Now, I have written an extension to format strings fluently like:

```
public static string FormatWith(this string me, params object[] args) {
    return string.Format(me, args);
}
```

So I can do:

[image]

Now I would like to implement similar syntax highlighting for the `{0}` and `{1}` whenever a string is followed by `.FormatWith`. Is this possible in ReSharper?

Comment: fyi, your method will fail if `me` is null.

Comment: @DanielA.White True, but so will string.Format() :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using StringFormatMethodAttribute in [JetBrains.Annotations package](https://nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations/).

```
[StringFormatMethod("me")]
public static string FormatWith(this string me, params object[] args) {
    return string.Format(me, args);
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks for the speedy response :)

Answer (score 2):

It might work with placing annotations on your extension method.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Annotations_in_Source_Code.html

There is more elaboration here.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html