# How to add custom coloring scheme to a specific pattern?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2015

On Visual Studio, when using

```
string.Format("bla {0}", someparameter);
```

the part of parameter "{0}" is colored green, and ReSharper (an external tool) is notifying on missing parameter when it's not supplied with the method.

In my project i use a lot of debug logs as follows:

```
_log.Debug("bla {0}", someparameter);
```

and i want to add the same kind of styling as mentioned above, with coloring, and perhaps an external tool as ReSharper to identify missing parameters.

The motivation is to avoid awkward issues in which i missed some parameter, or wrote the same parameter place holder twice

technical information:

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 RC (recently upgraded from VS 2012)
and ReSharper 9.1.

Comment: Dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939627) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092245). I picked the older as the dupe target.

Answer (score 1):

You can: `_log.Debug(string.format("Text {0})", params[]));`

Comment: i thought about adding / changing/ addon - something in the infrastructure

Comment: Your answer is trivial and not related to the question.